# MySQL calculated MAX() column from another table

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am trying to add a calculated value to one of my tables.

I have two MySQL tables with information about orders from my website. The first table `orders` contains metadata about the order and my second table `order_lines` contains the details for each line of the order.

Here is an example of my `order_lines` table

```
+----------+---------------+----------+
| order_id | item          | leadtime |
+----------+---------------+----------+
| 1        | iPhone 8      | 22       |
+----------+---------------+----------+
| 1        | Thinkpad T450 | 30       |
+----------+---------------+----------+
| 1        | SSD 1TB       | 10       |
+----------+---------------+----------+
```

I want to make a new column in a seperate table which shows the maximum value of `leadtime` for each `order_id`. It would look something like this:

```
+----------+--------------+
| order_id | max_leadtime |
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | 30           |
+----------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the max_leadtime for order_id `1` is 30 because 30 is the maximum value in the `order_lines` table where `order_id` is equal to `1`.

**I am trying to achieve this with**

```
ALTER TABLE
    orders ADD COLUMN max_leadtime INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (SELECT
        MAX(leadtime)
    FROM
        order_lines
    WHERE
        order_lines.order_id = orders.order_id)
) STORED
```

This throws the error "A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SELECT" at position 81)". This is confusing to me though as there is no previous statement.

Does anyone know how I could successfully generate this new column as a calculated value.

Comment: I don't think mysql supports select queries in generated columns https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html. You could try creating a view for your purpose.

Comment: "Subqueries are not permitted." see: [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)